# Calling Ruby on Rails controller method from another method in the same controller skips before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, when I call a controller method from another controller, the before_filter on the targeted method (the one being called) does not execute.

How can I get this to execute?

(Rough example code to follow)

```
before_filter :filter_method, :only => [:method_b]

def method_a
 if blahblahblah == x
   do_something
     render j
 else
   method_b
 end
end

def method_b
  do_something_else
end
```

so here filter_method would not execute, how can I change that without rewriting everything?

Comment: Generally you'd use a `redirect_to`, since calling a method directly will just call the method and isn't part of the normal Controller lifecycle.

Comment: @AnthonyMichaelCook redirect_to causes a "you can only render or redirect once per action" error

Comment: Then your example code above is not correct (also it is missing an `end`) in that case you must `return` after you `redirect_to`.

Comment: @AnthonyMichaelCook the do-something contains a render also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402605/redirect-to-and-render-with-return

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed how before_filter gets applied in rails. It's not applied when you call any method from where ever you want. It applies only when it maps request route to corresponding controller method. Before filter serves as guard process between request to controller method, not within it. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Before actions are only ran when an action is called on the controller, not if you call it yourself.

The proper way to handle this depends on what your methods do. The current way still renders the view from `method_b`. Most likely what you want is to redirect to that action but the current way and rendering `method_b` are both possible as well.

The current way (fixed):

Calls `method_b` with filter method and renders view from `method_a`

```
def method_a
 if blahblahblah == x
   do_something
 else
   filter_method
   method_b unless performed? # In case filter_method renders/redirects
end
```

Rendering:

Calls `method_b` with filter method and renders view from `method_b`

```
def method_a
 if blahblahblah == x
   do_something
 else
   filter_method
   method_b unless performed?
   render :method_b unless performed?
end
```

Redirecting:

Tells the client (browser) to make a new request to `method_b`. This calls `method_b` with the filter method and renders view from `method_b`.

```
def method_a
 if blahblahblah == x
   do_something
 else
   redirect_to :method_b
end
```

Try these ways and see what suits your problem best. I cannot make this decision for you since the code example is pretty bare.

Comment: @SlimLiser the views are actually unimportant. when I try any of those ways i get a "Can only render or redirect once per action" error, the do-something contains a render also

Comment: It sounds like your filter_method is rendering/redirecting already. Redirecting should still work from what I can see from the code you posted.

Comment: @SlimLiser I updated the code example, the render is in the if statement

Comment: does method_b contain a render/redirect as well?

Comment: In this case the render method does not suit you. Use the first way or redirecting. The first will work assuming your filter_method does not render/redirect. If it does, then just change the `method_b` call to  `method_b unless performed?`.

Redirecting should work without modifications.